# Unable to execute a query via PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a bunch of rows to have `nieaktualny` column (`TINYINT(1)`) modified from 0 to 1 for all rows with `email_1` field equal to values from array `$sprawdzone_temp`. I have tried many approaches, via `exec()`, `prepare()`, `execute()` but none seems to work and I just have no idea why. No errors pop up when try/catching. When I am using phpMyAdmin, the queries work just fine.

Here's my PHP:

```
$sql  = "UPDATE database.table SET `nieaktualny` = '1' WHERE `email_1` LIKE ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
foreach($sprawdzone_temp as $email) {
    $stmt->execute(array($email));
}
```

The array with data is fine, there seems to be something wrong with how I want to use PDO.

Comment: Have you checked the web server's error logs? Let's see your try/catch statement.

Comment: `nieaktualny` = '1' you are passing string value instead of boolean

Comment: I'm interested in `$sprawdzone_temp`  what value is there?

Comment: @JayBlanchard yes, sorry. No errors reported out there for this issue.
KARANLAGALWAR The *nieaktualny* is to be set to exactly 1, no other possibilities. I have tried nieaktualny = '1', nieaktualny=1 - they do not work.
MasivuyeCokile It's just an array. Edited for privacy reasons. https://pastebin.com/SSMQikkm Edit: here's the table structure https://i.imgur.com/WXxUOmD.png

Comment: @GrzegorzG. try the answer below

Comment: Lose the foreach() loop and use a literal value for the email pattern, PDO will give you a clue if you catch the exception

Comment: @symcbean When running the stmt with a single value copy-pasted manually, not via loop fetching from array, the query works fine. Is that what you meant? // $stmt->execute(array("some@addr.ess")); //

Comment: @GrzegorzG. see the updated answer?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your `$sprawdzone_temp` might not have the [SQL Wildcard Characters](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-wildcards.htm)

A wildcard character is used to substitute any other character(s) in a string.

Wildcard characters are used with the SQL LIKE operator. The LIKE operator is used in a WHERE clause to search for a specified pattern in a column.

There are two wildcards used in conjunction with the LIKE operator:

1. (%) - The percent sign represents zero, one, or multiple characters

2 . (_) - The underscore represents a single character

Therefore your code should be along these lines :

```
<?php

$sprawdzone_temp = "%".$sprawdzone_temp."%";
$sql  = "UPDATE database.table SET `nieaktualny` = 1 WHERE `email_1` LIKE ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
foreach($sprawdzone_temp as $email) {
    $stmt->execute(array($email));
}

if(!$stmt){

echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
print_r($db->errorInfo());  
}

?>
```

**Update**

I would suggest that you also try the SQL IN Operator, which  allows you to specify multiple values in a WHERE clause.

The IN operator is a shorthand for multiple OR conditions.

```
<?php

$sprawdzone_temp = array($nadawca);

$in = str_repeat('?,', count($sprawdzone_temp) - 1) . '?';

$sql  = "UPDATE database.table SET `nieaktualny` = 1 WHERE `email_1` in($in)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($sprawdzone_temp);
if (!$stmt) {
    echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
    print_r($db->errorInfo());
} else {

    echo "record updated";
}

?>
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried that: array is prepared with $sprawdzone_temp[] = "%".$nadawca."%";

Comment: and still not getting the results? whats the error message you are getting?

Comment: None. Neither from error_reporting(E_ALL), not from try/catch. Isn't it that I have to use some kind of bind_param?

Comment: try the updated answer, also do a `var_dump($stmt);` to see it it returns false or true

Comment: Still nothing. dump tells me: *object(PDOStatement)#4 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(88) "UPDATE baza23138_dev.bazy_dane_kopia SET `nieaktualny` = 1 WHERE `email_1` LIKE ?" } * The whole code looks like this: https://pastebin.com/AyL0agA9

Comment: @GrzegorzG. try removing the loop and `execute([sprawdzone_temp])`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150316/discussion-between-masivuye-cokile-and-grzegorz-g).

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**
I had to apply `strip_tags` to the emails that were later used in PDO query.

The issue was not in anything related to queries. The emails from the `$sprawdzone_temp` array were not prepared properly. When I `print_r`'ed the array, it looked normally, there was simply the proper email address without any spaces or similar. When I copy-pasted them from the `print_r` to phpMyAdmin, queries worked fine, but seemingly there was some illegal character that was interrupting the LIKE condition of SQL queries.

I have fixed that when I have randomly tried applying `strip_tags` when inserting the email addresses into the `$sprawdzone_temp` array. Now it works. Just out of curiosity - can I somehow print all the characters in a avalue - just to check what character was in there that caused the PDO query to stop?